# how to import mysql database in wavemaker

Tags: mysql, database, wavemaker

While importing I am getting an error

`Connection failed: SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

What could be the possible solution for this?

Comment: Too broad a question, let's narrow it down a bit: 1) are you sure the MySQL database server is running on your local machine 2) can you login to the database with some other tool, using the same credentials?

Answer (score 0):

Here are my notes on the subject. I had the same issue and saved these notes for future use. There are two methods that I know of for creating users and setting permissions-- I hope they are helpful.

```
mysql> select password('12345');
+-------------------------+
| password('123456') |
+-------------------------+
| 2ff898e158cd0311        | 
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> create user test identified by password '2ff898e158cd0311';
```

A) Expects @password to be a hash string 1 value:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES 
ON `mydb` . * TO 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED 
BY
PASSWORD '@password';
```

- Note the use of the PASSWORD keyword!

B) Expects @password to be a clear-text string value:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES 
ON `mydb` . * TO 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED 
BY '@password';
```